# Java: Is <? extends T> accepts T or just its subtypes?

Tags: java, generics

In java8 when I try to write this code

```
List<? extends String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
```

I get an error

> Required type:
>   capture of ? extends String - 
>   Provided:
>   String

When I try this code

```
List<String> stings1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> stings2 = new ArrayList<>();
stings1.addAll(stings2);
```

It works fine, however, the signature of addAll method is `boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);` and it shouldn't accept the same type it extends like the previous example.

I'm curious if `? extends T` should accept T or not!!

Comment: `? extends T` includes `T` itself. But that's not the root of the problem. You cannot add anything to the list, since `?` could be any subtype of `String`. So you can't add a `String`. You can only retrieve `String`s from the list, because any subtype of `String` is assignable to a `String` variable. See also [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: [Q: What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397)

Comment: Also note that `? extends String` does not make sense, since the `String` class is declared `final` and thus cannot be extended.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks now I understand it, also I just used string as example didn't intend to inherit it.